# What is causing the unexpected interaction between the string `eval`, code attributes, and the symbol table?

Tags: perl, symbol-table

I was trying to write some unit tests for a module that makes use of code attributes via `Attribute::Handlers`. Because of the way that the attributes might interact with child functions I wanted to run through a set of three nested subs with each combination of with and without attributes (so eight tests total). I wrote it with three loops using string `eval` to redefine the functions each iteration.

The original code made use of the function name, derived via `*{$symbol}{NAME}` and what I noticed was that sometimes the function name did not match up with the sub that had the attribute defined on it. It is predictable (*not really -- see example at the bottom*) and repeatable, but I don't understand why it's happening. I don't even really understand *what* is happening. The pattern, as I can see it, is that when a given function changes from with-attribute to without-attribute, the function *following* the one that lost the attribute has it's symbol name switch to the function that lost the attribute.

For example, if I have three functions, `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, where all three have the attribute in one iteration, and the middle one loses the attribute in the next iteration, the symbol names get reported as `foo` and `bar` even though the attributes are on `foo` and `baz`.

***NOTE:** that's not really the pattern -- see the example at the bottom.*

Here's the stripped down code with some added debug statements:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.036;

use Attribute::Handlers;

sub TestAttr : ATTR(CODE)
{
foreach my $arg (@_) { $arg //= ""; print "<$arg> "; }; print "\n";
    my ($package, $symbol, $referent, $attr, $data, $phase, $filename, $linenum) = @_;
    my $function_name = *{$symbol}{NAME};

say("FN: $function_name / $referent / $symbol / @$data");

    return;
}

my($sub_def_str) = <<EOS;
    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :FooAttr { }
    sub bar :BarAttr { }
    sub baz :BazAttr { }
EOS


foreach my $foo (":TestAttr(xFOO)", "") {
    foreach my $bar (":TestAttr(xBAR)", "") {
        foreach my $baz (":TestAttr(xBAZ)", "") {
            my($newdef) = "$sub_def_str";
            $newdef =~ s{ :FooAttr}{ $foo}g;
            $newdef =~ s{ :BarAttr}{ $bar}g;
            $newdef =~ s{ :BazAttr}{ $baz}g;

say("---------");
say("<$newdef>");
            eval "$newdef";
            die $@ if $@;
        }
    }
}
```

The first two iterations run fine:

```
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :TestAttr(xFOO) { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz :TestAttr(xBAZ) { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8)> <CODE(0x7f835c00e6e0)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c026888)> <CHECK> <(eval 5)> <3>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f835c00e6e0) / GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8) / xFOO
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835d808db8)> <CODE(0x7f835c00e668)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c00e698)> <CHECK> <(eval 5)> <4>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f835c00e668) / GLOB(0x7f835d808db8) / xBAR
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835c815718)> <CODE(0x7f835d808d70)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c82e798)> <CHECK> <(eval 5)> <5>
FN: baz / CODE(0x7f835d808d70) / GLOB(0x7f835c815718) / xBAZ
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :TestAttr(xFOO) { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz  { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8)> <CODE(0x7f835c839348)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c810980)> <CHECK> <(eval 9)> <3>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f835c839348) / GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8) / xFOO
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835d808db8)> <CODE(0x7f835d808dd0)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c810908)> <CHECK> <(eval 9)> <4>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f835d808dd0) / GLOB(0x7f835d808db8) / xBAR
```

but the third one shows the issue:

```
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :TestAttr(xFOO) { }
    sub bar  { }
    sub baz :TestAttr(xBAZ) { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8)> <CODE(0x7f835c810800)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c025df0)> <CHECK> <(eval 12)> <3>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f835c810800) / GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8) / xFOO
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835d808db8)> <CODE(0x7f835c810920)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c810938)> <CHECK> <(eval 12)> <5>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f835c810920) / GLOB(0x7f835d808db8) / xBAZ
```

The attribute is on `baz` as shown by the data (`xBAZ`) and the line number (`5`), but the symbol name is reported as `bar`. The same thing would have probably happened in the second iteration had there been a fourth sub. Here's the whole output (all 8 iterations):

```
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :TestAttr(xFOO) { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz :TestAttr(xBAZ) { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8)> <CODE(0x7f835c00e6e0)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c026888)> <CHECK> <(eval 5)> <3>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f835c00e6e0) / GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8) / xFOO
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835d808db8)> <CODE(0x7f835c00e668)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c00e698)> <CHECK> <(eval 5)> <4>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f835c00e668) / GLOB(0x7f835d808db8) / xBAR
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835c815718)> <CODE(0x7f835d808d70)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c82e798)> <CHECK> <(eval 5)> <5>
FN: baz / CODE(0x7f835d808d70) / GLOB(0x7f835c815718) / xBAZ
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :TestAttr(xFOO) { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz  { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8)> <CODE(0x7f835c839348)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c810980)> <CHECK> <(eval 9)> <3>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f835c839348) / GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8) / xFOO
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835d808db8)> <CODE(0x7f835d808dd0)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c810908)> <CHECK> <(eval 9)> <4>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f835d808dd0) / GLOB(0x7f835d808db8) / xBAR
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :TestAttr(xFOO) { }
    sub bar  { }
    sub baz :TestAttr(xBAZ) { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8)> <CODE(0x7f835c810800)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c025df0)> <CHECK> <(eval 12)> <3>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f835c810800) / GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8) / xFOO
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835d808db8)> <CODE(0x7f835c810920)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c810938)> <CHECK> <(eval 12)> <5>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f835c810920) / GLOB(0x7f835d808db8) / xBAZ
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :TestAttr(xFOO) { }
    sub bar  { }
    sub baz  { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8)> <CODE(0x7f835c00dcf0)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835d808a88)> <CHECK> <(eval 15)> <3>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f835c00dcf0) / GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8) / xFOO
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo  { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz :TestAttr(xBAZ) { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8)> <CODE(0x7f835c815ef8)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c8109c8)> <CHECK> <(eval 17)> <4>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f835c815ef8) / GLOB(0x7f835c00e5d8) / xBAR
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835c815718)> <CODE(0x7f835d808f50)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c0260d8)> <CHECK> <(eval 17)> <5>
FN: baz / CODE(0x7f835d808f50) / GLOB(0x7f835c815718) / xBAZ
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo  { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz  { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835d808db8)> <CODE(0x7f835c815ef8)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835c810620)> <CHECK> <(eval 20)> <4>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f835c815ef8) / GLOB(0x7f835d808db8) / xBAR
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo  { }
    sub bar  { }
    sub baz :TestAttr(xBAZ) { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f835d808db8)> <CODE(0x7f835c00e6c8)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f835d808a88)> <CHECK> <(eval 22)> <5>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f835c00e6c8) / GLOB(0x7f835d808db8) / xBAZ
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo  { }
    sub bar  { }
    sub baz  { }
>
```

On a whim I switched the middle iteration from ON/OFF to OFF/ON, and the pattern stayed the same *except in the final iteration*. So my loops change to this:

```perl
foreach my $foo (":TestAttr(xFOO)", "") {
    foreach my $bar ("", ":TestAttr(xBAR)") {
        foreach my $baz (":TestAttr(xBAZ)", "") {
```

and the final two iterations look like this:

```
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo  { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz :TestAttr(xBAZ) { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750819b70)> <CODE(0x7f8750812378)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f8750818c30)> <CHECK> <(eval 20)> <4>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f8750812378) / GLOB(0x7f8750819b70) / xBAR
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750819bd0)> <CODE(0x7f8752018948)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f8750855580)> <CHECK> <(eval 20)> <5>
FN: baz / CODE(0x7f8752018948) / GLOB(0x7f8750819bd0) / xBAZ
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo  { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz  { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8)> <CODE(0x7f8750828090)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f875086ab20)> <CHECK> <(eval 23)> <4>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f8750828090) / GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8) / xBAR
```

The `foo` sub didn't lose its attribute yet the `bar` function name is showing up as `foo`, so now I'm truly lost.

The full output with the switched middle iteration is:

```
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :TestAttr(xFOO) { }
    sub bar  { }
    sub baz :TestAttr(xBAZ) { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8)> <CODE(0x7f87500130e0)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f8750812378)> <CHECK> <(eval 5)> <3>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f87500130e0) / GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8) / xFOO
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750819bd0)> <CODE(0x7f8750819d50)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f875086ab08)> <CHECK> <(eval 5)> <5>
FN: baz / CODE(0x7f8750819d50) / GLOB(0x7f8750819bd0) / xBAZ
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :TestAttr(xFOO) { }
    sub bar  { }
    sub baz  { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8)> <CODE(0x7f87500130c8)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f875086abc8)> <CHECK> <(eval 8)> <3>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f87500130c8) / GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8) / xFOO
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :TestAttr(xFOO) { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz :TestAttr(xBAZ) { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8)> <CODE(0x7f87508188e8)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f875086ab38)> <CHECK> <(eval 10)> <3>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f87508188e8) / GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8) / xFOO
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750819b70)> <CODE(0x7f8750013098)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f8750013248)> <CHECK> <(eval 10)> <4>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f8750013098) / GLOB(0x7f8750819b70) / xBAR
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750819bd0)> <CODE(0x7f8750828930)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f875086ac28)> <CHECK> <(eval 10)> <5>
FN: baz / CODE(0x7f8750828930) / GLOB(0x7f8750819bd0) / xBAZ
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo :TestAttr(xFOO) { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz  { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8)> <CODE(0x7f8750819c90)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f875086b108)> <CHECK> <(eval 14)> <3>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f8750819c90) / GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8) / xFOO
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750819b70)> <CODE(0x7f87500126c0)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f8752009b98)> <CHECK> <(eval 14)> <4>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f87500126c0) / GLOB(0x7f8750819b70) / xBAR
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo  { }
    sub bar  { }
    sub baz :TestAttr(xBAZ) { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750819b70)> <CODE(0x7f8750819c90)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f875086ac28)> <CHECK> <(eval 17)> <5>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f8750819c90) / GLOB(0x7f8750819b70) / xBAZ
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo  { }
    sub bar  { }
    sub baz  { }
>
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo  { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz :TestAttr(xBAZ) { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750819b70)> <CODE(0x7f8750812378)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f8750818c30)> <CHECK> <(eval 20)> <4>
FN: bar / CODE(0x7f8750812378) / GLOB(0x7f8750819b70) / xBAR
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750819bd0)> <CODE(0x7f8752018948)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f8750855580)> <CHECK> <(eval 20)> <5>
FN: baz / CODE(0x7f8752018948) / GLOB(0x7f8750819bd0) / xBAZ
---------
<    no warnings qw(redefine);

    sub foo  { }
    sub bar :TestAttr(xBAR) { }
    sub baz  { }
>
<main> <GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8)> <CODE(0x7f8750828090)> <TestAttr> <ARRAY(0x7f875086ab20)> <CHECK> <(eval 23)> <4>
FN: foo / CODE(0x7f8750828090) / GLOB(0x7f8750012fd8) / xBAR
```

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: Perhaps you can reduce your problem a bit more so it is easier to evaluate it.

Comment: @TLP - I'm not really sure what more I can cut out, other than the debug output, but that's needed to show the issue. The issue can be reproduced with just two subs/two loops but then it's just seen the one time. I would suggest looking at just the second set of output I posted, iteration three of the looping ("but the third one shows the issue:"). Thank you!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't try to do this in one program, I think. Write new scripts from templates and run them in their own process so they don't have cross effects.

Comment: @briandfoy - There are lots of ways to work around it, I have no worries about that. It seems like it /should/ work, though, so it leads me to think that I'm missing some fundamental understanding of attributes and the parameters I'm being passed by Attribute::Handlers, and I'd like to figure that out before continuing to use them. And if it's a possible bug (far less likely than user error, but still a non-zero chance), I'd like to file a report.

Comment: @JoeCasadonte Well, no, what you have here is a short story. My advice to you is trim the code down to bare bones that still shows the problem. Cut the storytelling, just show expected and actual output. My guess is that since the module allows for redefining code references, it does something magic under the hood, and what you think is removing attributes is something else. You know you don't have to do this dynamically with loops and eval, you could just hardcode everything and see if that repeats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Attribute::Handlers` uses a cache for symbol lookups in `A::H::findsym()`. There seems to be a problem with redefinitions of subs not invalidating the cache. If I comment out line 12 in `Attribute::Handlers`:

```
#   return $symcache{$pkg,$ref} if $symcache{$pkg,$ref};
```

everything works as expected.

Comment: Perl bug filed: https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/21718